# Rails 3 standard notifications list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, notifications

One of the coolest thing in Rails 3 is notifications. But I would like to ask if there is a list of all notifications names that I can subscribe to?

I couldn't find it in documentation (only few examples), so I can only go to the code if I don't find the answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like a comprehensive list

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#render_partial-
action_view

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the exact same thing. It seems there's no documentation on this, so I browsed the code and compiled the following list.

Note that the `===` operator is used for matching, so you can use a string or a regex when subscribing

```
receive.action_mailer
deliver.action_mailer

write_fragment.action_controller
read_fragment.action_controller
exist_fragment?.action_controller
expire_fragment.action_controller

expire_page.action_controller
write_page.action_controller

start_processing.action_controller
process_action.action_controller
send_file.action_controller
send_data.action_controller
redirect_to.action_controller
halted_callback.action_controller

render_collection.action_view
render_partial.action_view
render_template.action_view
!render_template.action_view

sql.active_record

cache_read.active_support
cache_fetch_hit.active_support
cache_generate.active_support
cache_write.active_support
cache_delete.active_support
cache_exist?.active_support

deprecation.rails

render
```

Answer (score 1):

**config/initializers/notifications.rb**

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe "process_action.action_controller" do |name, start, finish, id, payload|
      PageRequest.create! do |page_request|
        page_request.path = payload[:path]
        page_request.page_duration = (finish - start) * 1000
        page_request.view_duration = payload[:view_runtime]
        page_request.db_duration = payload[:db_runtime]
      end
    end
```

more info [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3)

Comment: But there are only few examples, what i wanted to ask is to have full list of available notifications

Comment: @Said, can you tell something about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665016/rails-activesupport-notifications-wrong-db-runtime-value ?