# rails activesupport notifications - wrong db runtime value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activesupport

I'm trying to log requests for my REST API application. I'm using rails notifications for this , like here http://railscasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3

I can't understand how to solve one problem with rails notifications.

my initializer code

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe "process_action.action_controller" do |name, start, finish, id, payload|
 p name
 p start 
 p finish
 p id
 p payload
end



Controller respond section

    class PostsController < ApplicationController
      # GET /posts
      # GET /posts.json

      respond_to  :json, :html
     ....
end
```

Controller create action

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    @post.save!
    respond_with(@post, :location => nil)
 end
```

Console output

```
"process_action.action_controller"
2013-02-02 20:13:11 +0200
2013-02-02 20:13:11 +0200
"951b8999e9b71d4a8949"
{:controller=>"PostsController", :action=>"create", :params=>{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1WugY9gh6ZCRXjfBTuckye3c9XDvtCqMQ2JdBpCo88s=", "post"=>{"name"=>"post3", "title"=>"post3", "content"=>"post3"}, "commit"=>"Create Post", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"posts"}, :format=>:html, :method=>"POST", :path=>"/posts", :status=>302, :view_runtime=>nil, :db_runtime=>0}
```

As you can see  **:db_runtime=>0**

However if I change controller action code to default scaffold

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    #@post.save!
    #respond_with(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I can see

```
"process_action.action_controller"
2013-02-02 20:22:51 +0200
2013-02-02 20:22:51 +0200
"bf2a3173c08a0fd9008e"
{:controller=>"PostsController", :action=>"create", :params=>{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1WugY9gh6ZCRXjfBTuckye3c9XDvtCqMQ2JdBpCo88s=", "post"=>{"name"=>"post3", "title"=>"post3", "content"=>"post3"}, "commit"=>"Create Post", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"posts"}, :format=>:html, :method=>"POST", :path=>"/posts", :status=>302, :view_runtime=>nil, :db_runtime=>4.727}
```

**:db_runtime=>4.727**

What is the reason of that and how I can fix it to make it work in first example ?
Thanks !

UPD

```
 bundle show rails
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rails-3.2.11
rvm current
ruby-1.9.3-p125
```

UPD2

It seems like it doesn't work when I use respond_with! Can someone tell me why? 
Thanks

Comment: hi Fivell, just now i tried to generate the same thing. here what i'm getting with using respond_with: Notification: process_action.action_controller 2013-02-06 13:59:21 +0600 2013-02-06 13:59:21 +0600 f2da3803410cccda546a {:controller=>"PostsController", :action=>"show", :params=>{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"posts", "id"=>"12"}, :format=>:html, :method=>"GET", :path=>"/posts/12", :status=>200, :view_runtime=>9.479712, :db_runtime=>0.267212}

Comment: rails 3.2.11,
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: hi, Said it works with GET, but not with POST

Comment: Hi, here's my post request: Notification: process_action.action_controller 2013-02-07 12:44:53 +0600 2013-02-07 12:44:53 +0600 6b876f07776723b5ac92 {:controller=>"PostsController", :action=>"create", :params=>{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"V/Y4apQ4S4Qxb0A9hmZvNX6C1jCQQ469YTNezlOpsq0=", "post"=>{"title"=>"asd", "content"=>"asd"}, "commit"=>"Create Post", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"posts"}, :format=>:html, :method=>"POST", :path=>"/posts", :status=>406, :view_runtime=>nil, :db_runtime=>353.078918

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev, can you make your post request to return status 200 instead of 406 ?  try to add  respond_to  :json, :html to your controller code

Comment: and remove :location => nil from respond_with method

Comment: ahhh, i see then, getting 0, it's really strange.

Comment: ok) then I'm not crazy!!!!

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev, I think it's a bug in rails!

Comment: ahh you're not crazy, did you try to create an issue in github?

Comment: not yet, I am debugging right now to find buggy place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems like a bug. Let see, what's going on:

First of all, we have AR railtie for controller action and its implementation for setting db_runtime by using cleanup_view_runtime hook

```
def cleanup_view_runtime
      if ActiveRecord::Base.connected?
       db_rt_before_render = ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.reset_runtime
       runtime = super
       db_rt_after_render = ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.reset_runtime
       self.db_runtime = db_rt_before_render + db_rt_after_render
       runtime - db_rt_after_render
     else
       super
     end
end
```

App calls controller action -> action doing some db queries and renders some stuff -> before and after rendering AR Logger saves runtime data. Good.

Let see how works respond_with

```
def respond_with(*resources, &block)
  raise "In order to use respond_with, first you need to declare the formats your " <<
        "controller responds to in the class level" if self.class.mimes_for_respond_to.empty?

  if collector = retrieve_collector_from_mimes(&block)
    options = resources.size == 1 ? {} : resources.extract_options!
    options[:default_response] = collector.response
    (options.delete(:responder) || self.class.responder).call(self, resources, options)
  end
end

def self.call(*args)
  new(*args).respond
end

def to_format
  if get? || !has_errors? || response_overridden?
    default_render
  else
    display_errors
  end
rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate => e
  api_behavior(e)
end
```

It seems like too much code here, but you should see the callstack for this issue: respond_with -> self.class.responder.respond -> self.class.responder.to_format -> default_render -> default_renderer raise ActionView::MissingTemplate(because we don't have any). At this moment we can see implementation for rendering :json and :xml(api_behaviour) through catching ActionView::MissingTemplate.

Now we know how respond_with works, but AR Logger does'nt know..
cleanup_view_runtime hook is called twice: for default_renderer(at that time template data was prepared and some db queries were called, but we catch ActionView::MissingTemplate in rendering proccess)

```
db_rt_before_render = ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.reset_runtime
runtime = super # <-- here
db_rt_after_render = ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.reset_runtime
```

and for api_behavour(at that time all template data was ready for rendering and no db queries)

Some messy explanation, but I hope it will be helpful :)

Comment: Yes Dmitry, debugger helped me to find it today, did you see issue with solution , that I did  about a hour ago https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9215

Comment: so now I'm trying to understand in what part of rails there are tests for notifications

Comment: The bounty should be yours! anyway I appreciate that :)

Answer (score 0):

The Rails instrumentation works by wrapping the request at the Rack metal level and recording events for the different metrics.  In both cases, the entire block should be wrapped and tracked by the standard instrumentation.

The only difference I can see after digging into the source is calling save() vs. save!().  It looks like the underlying method event subscriptions in ActiveRecord may behave differently.

Try changing your respond_with() example to use save vs. save! and see if it records the db_runtime properly?  If so, that's a Rails bug, and you can work around it by mimicking the save! features using save.

Comment: I'm puzzled as well.  Sorry that didn't pan out.

Comment: Winfield! Help me to understand what's going on!))

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

It's not straightforward and needs some tweak around..

Not unless you write your own Railtie to hook into this like `Active Record`, but it's a bit more complex than copying what `Active Record` has...

But here's how it does it:

1) [Log Subscriber](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb)

2) [Railtie](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L81)

3) [Controller Runtime](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb)

I hope that you got the hint of how to start getting into it.

Cheers!

Comment: actually it  looks like a bug in rails